# How to add gerrit change ID to an older commit?

Tags: git, gerrit, atlassian-sourcetree

Few commits back, I made a commit that doesn't have change ID. This unfortunately happens whenever you merge branches in source-tree without unchecking "Commit merge immediately".

I urgently need to push the code to Gerrit now, but I can't because one of the commits doesn't have change ID.

How can I re-add change ID to an older commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the commit history is `A-B-C-D-E` and the change id in `B` is missing. I'm not a source-tree user, so I'll give commands in the terminal:

```
git reset B --hard
#assuming you have installed the hook commit-msg that generates the change id.
git commit --amend
git cherry-pick C D E
#OR: git cherry-pick B..E
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to copy the IDS of C, B and E. How can I find those commit IDS now, after I reset head to B?

Comment: Run `git reflog` to find where you were before the hard reset. That reflog entry tells the commit hash of `E`. `git log E` will show the commits of `C`, `D`, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help! There's another problem though: `Commit E is a merge but no -m option was given.` Do you have any idea how to continue?

Comment: @TomášZato If it's a merge commit and if all the commits between `B` and `E` have been re-applied, just ignore it. If `Require Change-Id in commit message` of your gerrit project is true, any local merge commit should be removed by `rebase` or `cherry-pick` before you push the ref, because a local merge commit has no change id by default. It's not proper or necessary to add change id in a merge commit because such commit is not to be reviewed.

Answer (score 4):

You can do an interactive rebase on `origin/master` assuming `origin/master` is the remote HEAD you are working with. You can replace `origin/master` with whatever you wish.

```
git rebase -i origin/master
```

When doing that it will be prompt all commit ahead of `origin/master` on my example. You have to pick all commit but the one without Change-ID. For that one you need to edit the message. Doing that the change-ID will be automatically added.

***External resources :*** [Git interactive Rebase](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/git-interactive-rebase-squash-amend-rewriting-history)